# Задать запрос с помощью CDbCriteria

Tags: php, yii

Нужно такой запрос задать с помощью `CDbCriteria`:

```
select t_devices.* 
from t_departmens, t_branches, t_cabinets, t_employees, t_devices
where t_branches.id_organization = 1
and t_departmens.id_branch = t_branches.id_branch
and t_cabinets.id_department = t_departmens.id_department
and t_employees.id_cabinet = t_cabinets.id_cabinet
and t_devices.id_employee = t_employees.id_employee
```

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте так, сделано по мотивам [официальных доков](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbCriteria):

```
$criteria = new CDbCriteria;
$criteria->with = array('t_departmens',
                        't_branches', 
                        't_cabinets',
                        't_employees',
                        't_devices');
$criteria->together = true;
$criteria->select = array('t_devices.*');
$criteria->condition = "t_branches.id_organization = 1
                        and t_departmens.id_branch = t_branches.id_branch
                        and t_cabinets.id_department = t_departmens.id_department
                        and t_employees.id_cabinet = t_cabinets.id_cabinet
                        and t_devices.id_employee = t_employees.id_employee";
```

Comment: Такая ошибка

CDbException

Relation "t_departmens" is not defined in active record class "Device".